# Unable to set INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS=true using spring beans

Tags: spring, selenium, jbehave

I am using JBehave and Selenium to build a test framework for browser based acceptance testing. Used sample code at https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-tutorial/tree/master/etsy-selenium/java-spring to start off my project, working pretty good but hit a issue now.

My test cases are running fine on Firefox, but nothing works on IE8. Simple find By clauses are failing on IE.

```
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0'
Driver info: driver.version: BaseFluentWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:125)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id ==    search-box (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Searching online it seems like I need to set INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS=true and struggling to set that in the spring bean .xml config.

This is what I currently have, please suggest corrections or let me know if I am completely going the wrong way to solve this issue.

```
<bean id="browserCapabilities" class="org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities" >
   <constructor-arg index="0" value="internet explorer"/>
   <constructor-arg index="1" value="8"/>
   <constructor-arg index="2" value="WINDOWS"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ieDriverCapabilitySetter" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="browserCapabilities" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="setCapability" />
    <property name="arguments">
    <list>                
<value>org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS</value>
        <value>true</value>
    </list>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="driverProvider" class="org.jbehave.web.selenium.RemoteWebDriverProvider" >
    <constructor-arg ref="browserCapabilities"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: No. This is not what you are meant to do. You are meant to fix the [underlying issue](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html). Your solution is just going to cover up the problem and lead to unexpected, unexplained behaviour further down the line....what code are you using, what site are you running against and what version of Selenium are you using?

Comment: I went through [underlying issue](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html) and it makes sense now. thx